# How to add Toggle Button Behavior to MDFloatingActionButton in KivyMD?

Tags: python, button, kivy, toggle, kivymd

How to add radio button behavior to MDFloatingActionButton widget? Is there such a possibility or is it impossible?

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ToggleButtonBehavior


KV = '''
MDScreen:
    MDFloatingActionButton :
        icon : "torch"
        pos_hint : {"center_x":.5,"center_y":.5}
        theme_text_color : "Custom"
        text_color : [1,0,0,1]
        user_font_size : 60
        elevation : 12
        md_bg_color : [0,1,0,1]
'''

class Myapp(MDApp, ToggleButtonBehavior):
    def build(self):**



        return Builder.load_string(KV)


Myapp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't add `ToggleButtonBehavior` to the `App`. You should add it to the `MDFloatingActionButton`. You can do that by defining a custom class in your `kv`:

```
<MyMDFloatingActionButton@ToggleButtonBehavior+MDFloatingActionButton>:  # defined custom class

MDScreen:
    MyMDFloatingActionButton:  # uses the above custom class
        icon : "torch"
        pos_hint : {"center_x":.5,"center_y":.5}
        theme_text_color : "Custom"
        text_color : [1,0,0,1]
        user_font_size : 60
        elevation : 12
        md_bg_color : [0,1,0,1]
```

See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.lang.html#dynamic-classes).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I looked at the documentation but did not understand how to apply it specifically in my case. If you don't mind explaining how to apply it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You apply it by putting the `kv` code in my answer into your `KV` string.